# Issue with mule vmconnector to receive from more than 20 one-way inbound endpoints

Tags: mule

I am having the following problem concerning asynchronous (or one-way) vm inbound endpoints. In the tests below, it seems that the number of one-way inbound endpoints is limited to 20 per vmconnector. My question is: Is there a setting on the vmconnector or a way programmatically to configure the vmconnector to remove this limitation?

I am using Mule 3.3.1 CE.

Thanks.

test1 (will fail to reach secondFlow unless the 21nd endpoint uses vmConn2):

```
<mule ..>
<stdio:connector name="stdioConn" messageDelayTime="1000" promptMessage="prompt >"/>
<vm:connector name="vmConn"/>
<vm:connector name="vmConn2"/>
<flow name="FirstFlow">
<stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN" connector-ref="stdioConn"/>
<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path21" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
</flow>
<flow name="SecondFlow">
<composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path1" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path2" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path3" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
....
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path20" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path21" connector-ref="vmConn"/>
</composite-source>
<logger message="MESSAGE RECEIVED!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

test2 (same test with 21 flows):

```
<flow name="Flow1" >
<stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN" connector-ref="stdioConn"/>
<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path21" connector-ref="vmConn" />
</flow>
<flow name="Flow2">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path1" connector-ref="vmConn" doc:name="VM" />
<logger message="MESSAGE RECEIVED!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
<flow name="Flow3">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path2" connector-ref="vmConn" doc:name="VM" />
<logger message="MESSAGE RECEIVED!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
...
<flow name="Flow21">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path20" connector-ref="vmConn" doc:name="VM" />
<logger message="MESSAGE RECEIVED!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
<flow name="Flow22">
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="path21" connector-ref="vmConn" doc:name="VM" />
<logger message="MESSAGE RECEIVED!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any vm connector has a thread pool of message receivers. Once the receiver are exhausted new vm inbound endpoint want be able to process messages.

To address it you should increase the number of message receivers configuring [threading profiles properly](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Increasing the maxThreadsActive on the receiver-threading-profile did solve the problem.